# When hovering over parent div change image and heading at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I need to be able to change the color of the my headings and the picture when the user hovers over the parent div.  It works individually meaning when I hover over id="cf" the picture changes, but not the title and visa versa but not at the same time.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cf img").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0)");
  }, function(){
    $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(1)");
  });

  $(".blue-bar-info").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "pink");
  }, function(){
    $(this).css("background", "blue");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cf">
Picture
<div id="blue-bar" class="blue-bar-info">
    <div class="inner"> 
     <h4>Title</h4> 
     <span>Sub Title</span>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you be please more specific about your end result

Comment: I'd suggest you don't use JS for this. CSS is much better suited, and performs much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this I'd suggest you instead use CSS. It was designed for the purpose of changing the UI, performs much better than JS and avoids the possible FOUC when the page loads.

To do this, you can set the default styles, then override them in the `:hover` pseudo-selector, like this:

```css
#cf img { 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#cf:hover img { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); }

#cf .blue-bar-info { background-color: pink; }
#cf:hover .blue-bar-info { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cf">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KwkmSK4.jpg"/>
  <div id="blue-bar" class="blue-bar-info">
    <div class="inner">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <span>Sub Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS solution, but recommend is use CSS for this ;)

```
 $("#cf").hover(function(){
            $("#cf img").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0)");
            $(".blue-bar-info").css("background", "pink");
        }, function(){
            $("#cf img").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(1)");
            $(".blue-bar-info").css("background", "blue");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cf img, .blue-bar-info").hover(function () {
            $('#cf img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0)");
            $('.blue-bar-info').css("background", "pink");
        }, function () {
            $('#cf img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(1)");
            $('.blue-bar-info').css("background", "blue");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is fine except you are using wrong selector for parent div in your code.

Can `$("#cf")` instead of `$("#cf img")` solve your problem?